# Centos Apache Mod Vhosts Alias returns error 500

Tags: apache, laravel, centos, url-rewriting, vhosts

I am not able to convert this (working) virtual host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.1.2.3.4.xip.io
    ServerAlias *.test.1.2.3.4.xip.io
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/test/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/test/public">
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Into this more versatile one (using mod_vhosts_alias)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ServerAlias *.1.2.3.4.xip.io
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/%1/public"
    <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/*/public">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm on Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) CentOS release 6.6 (Final) AllowOverride is set to None on / in httpd.conf

I get

```
[Thu Aug 06 14:37:37 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 PHP/5.5.25 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 06 14:37:39 2015] [error] [client 1.2.3.4] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Even setting that LogLevel I can't get more info.

This is also my .htaccess just in case (it's Laravel default one)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks